Typescript error in React Navigation's LinkingOptions: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'. initialRouteName?: never

My whole LinkingOptions:
const linking: LinkingOptions<StackParamList> = {
  prefixes: ['myapp://', 'https://myapp.com'],
  config: {
    initialRouteName: 'Drawer', // this is fine
    screens: {
      Drawer: {
        initialRouteName: 'HomeDrawerItem', // this is fine
        screens: {
          ProductDrawerItem: {
            initialRouteName: 'ProductHome', // <<< red squiggle underline here
            screens: {
              ProductHome: 'product/list',
              ProductDetail: 'product/:item/:productId',
              ProductStore: 'store/:domain',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

The whole thing is working, only initialRouteName: 'ProductHome' that has this error?
Any idea why and how to fix it? I mean, it's working, I can just @ts-ignore it, but I'd rather not, I feel like I'm doing something wrong here?

you can also add as never type at the end like so
initialRouteName: 'ProductHome' as never. This will make the error go away as well.
